# Unable to deploy node app on heroku. Displays only welcome message

Tags: node.js, heroku

heroku logs

```
 2018-04-20T20:45:50.151330+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:45:50.059558+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:45:50.059558+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:45:50.151330+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:46:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:46:58.098188+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2b289e67 by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:46:58.098188+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:46:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
 2018-04-20T20:46:58.115335+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ghsklat2378123@gmail.com
 2018-04-20T20:47:00.895268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
 2018-04-20T20:47:03.518908+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2018-04-20T20:47:03.518933+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
 2018-04-20T20:47:03.518931+00:00 app[web.1]: > stywqrrd@1.0.0 start /app
 2018-04-20T20:47:03.518935+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2018-04-20T20:47:03.875652+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000
 2018-04-20T20:48:01.013365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
 2018-04-20T20:48:01.013866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
 2018-04-20T20:48:01.152301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 2018-04-20T20:48:01.155261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
 2018-04-20T20:48:01.132422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
 2018-04-20T20:48:02.894892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
 2018-04-20T20:48:05.106690+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2018-04-20T20:48:05.106708+00:00 app[web.1]: > sstywqrrd@1.0.0 start /app
 2018-04-20T20:48:05.106710+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
 2018-04-20T20:48:05.106712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2018-04-20T20:48:05.295340+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000
```

This is a very simple node app that i'm unable to deploy. When I got the link it displays:`heroku welcome to you new app. Refer to documentation if you need help deploying`. Logs don't show any error(all logs shown in blue color). How do I solve this?

Cloned the repo and then did
git init, git add, git commit

`heroku create` 
`heroku git:remote -a safe-forest-59278` 
`heroku apps:create myappName` 
`git push heroku master`

Comment: are you specifying port `3000` explicitly in your server code ?

Comment: inshort your log statements says that you've got some uncaught exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to log statement

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT
within 60 seconds of launch
```

This simply means that the port your are trying to connect with is not available for some reason.

And most probably you're specifying the port like

`port = 3000`

You should change this line to

`port = process.env.PORT || 3000`

This will let `heroku` servers to assign an available port to your server to listen to.

Why this happens is because mostly the ports that you specify while developing an application, there are very rare chances for that ports to be available and open in production.